# Will Julia's GC continue to stop-the-world when parallelism is introduction?

Tags: garbage-collection, julia

Julia will have [multi-threading soon](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/1790). I'm curious to know the impact on its GC algorithm.

At one point in the thread, Stefan says that "Memory allocation will always be thread-local." If Julia will always use thread-local storage, doesn't that mean it could GC on threads independently, preventing most/all stop-the-world scenarios, similar to Erlang's BEAM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initially it will still be stop-the-world: there will be a barrier stopping all threads, the threads all mark in parallel, then there will be another barrier and the threads all sweep in parallel; as soon as they are done they can continue without further synchronization. In the future, however, there could be more concurrent GC implementations, maybe even as the default. That would be a pretty significant bit of work to implement, however.